# Memory leaks when using methods of Apple PoseNet model

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, graphics, coreml

I am using code from example «[Detecting Human Body Poses in an Image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/detecting_human_body_poses_in_an_image#overview)» (source is available by Download in link).
When I launching this code on my iPhone 7+ there is major increase of usage memory, after my device heats up and application will crashed.
In my code I am using `predict` method of `Posenet` class. After debugging I realized problem appears when there is calling model, but I don’t know how to fix it.

```
func predict(_ image: CGImage) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let input = PoseNetInput(image: image, size: self.modelInputSize)
        //Problem is below
        guard let prediction = try? self.poseNetMLModel.prediction(from: input) else {
            return
        }
        //Problem is above
        let poseNetOutput = PoseNetOutput(prediction: prediction,
                                          modelInputSize: self.modelInputSize,
                                          modelOutputStride: self.outputStride)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.delegate?.poseNet(self, didPredict: poseNetOutput)
        }
    }
}
```

Method is called from `captureOutput`.
What is the problem? How to fix it?

P.S.
This is memory usage after 1,5 minutes starting app. When memory usage is reaching 600 MGB application is crashed.
[image: Memory usage after 1,5 minutes starting app]

A lot of memory leaks and CVObject memory usage. But I don't know how to fix it.
[image: CVObject memory usage]

[image]

Comment: These leaks are irrelevant to your app memory usage issues. You're blaming leaks (total size of them is +- 250kB), but your app is consuming 180MB of memory and 600MB later. You're clearly not releasing something, you can have strong reference cycle, ... The code you shared is copy & paste from the sample. I tried to run the sample code on my old iPhone SE and my memory usage is below 70MB even after a couple of minutes. Share your code, what you're actually doing, not the verbatim copy of the sample code.

Comment: It also depends on where `predict()` is being called from. I'm assuming it's from a loop of some kind. You may need to throw an `autoreleasepool` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem in iOS version. It had been iOS 13.0.1 and when I updated it up to 13.5.1 problem was solved.